# Get the customized Response JSON from 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, maven

I have a Java Springboot microservice which calls a third-party API. For one of my test cases, the API returns 422 Unprocessable entity with a customized Response JSON Body

```
{
    "request_status": "error",
    "status": "error",
    "requested_url": "www.example.de",
    "url": "http://www.newexample.de/",
    "issue": "redirect",
    "recommendedUrl": true,
    "error_message": "The web address you entered redirects to another website."
}
```

I am unable to retrieve this response body in my microservice. My code is like below

```
try {
    HttpEntity<Input_Class> httpentity = new HttpEntity<Input_Class>(                      inputClassObj, headers);
    responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, httpentity,
         new ParameterizedTypeReference<Output_Class>() {});

} catch(RestClientException ue) {
     if (ue instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
         String errorResponse = ((HttpStatusCodeException) ue).getResponseBodyAsString();
         logger.info(errorResponse);
}
```

The errorResponse I could see in the log is

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "errorMessage": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

Can someone let me know which Exception class I should use to get the response body sent by the API.

Comment: Have you tried [`RestClientResponseException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestClientResponseException.html) instead of `RestClientException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    catch(RestClientException ue) {
     if (ue instanceof HttpStatusCodeException) {
         String errorResponse = ((HttpStatusCodeException) ue).getResponseBodyAsString();
         logger.info(errorResponse);
}
```

This code block actually works. errorResponse returns the response JSON. I was using another endpoint url which was wrapping up the response & therefore, did not get the actual response.